# WPF no setter for datagrid.ItemsSource. How to bind it to a multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, setter

I need to bind a datagrids itemsource to a multibinding, 
I found examples like this:
[using "ctrl:datagrid.ItemsSource>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875773/wpf-datagrid-combining-timeseries-w-multibinding-lose-change-notification-wh)

However nowhere is it explained how to access the datagrid.ItemsSource property in the xaml
What class needs to be written in the namespace "ctrl" in the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is about the `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`, you would write it without a XAML namespace prefix:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="...">
            <Binding ... />
            <Binding ... />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
</DataGrid>
```